# Javascript Object : How to Remove Square Brackets

Tags: javascript, json

I have this Js Obect, I need to trim/remove **one set of square braces** "the outermost ones [  ]" from the object . Below is the structure:

```
[[{"id":"5","color":"red",nges":[{"monthindex":3},{"monthindex":3"}]},{"id":"5","color":"red""nges":[{"monthindex":3"},{"monthindex":3"}]}]]
```

How can this be done , I did via PHP before sending it to JS but that didn,t help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to the Magento platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that your JavaScript object is invalid, why wouldn't a simple `newObj = oldObj[0]` work?